# EF Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

Which of the following queries performs better? They both have the same result.

Some extra info about the schema: the `JobId` is held in the `Employee` table. The `JobPermission` table has a `UNIQUE` `JobId` column (resulting in a 1-1 relation).

Query #1:

```
(from emp in db.Employees select emp.Job.JobPermissions).Single().Single()
```

Query #2:

```
(from emp in db.Employees join job in db.Jobs on emp.JobId equals job.JobId join permission in db.JobPermissions on job.JobId equals permission.JobId where emp.EmployeeId == empId select permission).Single()
```

I've measured the query execution time both locally and remotely but the results were unpredictable. The difference between them was marginal 99% of the time (~0.01s).

Does the readability of the #1 query outweigh the possible performance differences?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: @EricJ. I just noted that my tests were inconclusive. I'm asking if someone can shed some more light on this. I've edited the question to include one more sub question.

Comment: Your tests are very conclusive (assuming you ran them against data representative of production data).  There is no meaningful runtime difference.  `The difference between them was marginal 99% of the time (~0.01s).`

Comment: the best way to do this is to profile, which you did, so I garee with EricJ, there is no real question here. Query 1 in my opinion is easier to read, but why the `.Single().Single()`

Comment: @3dd `(from emp in db.Employees select emp.Job.JobPermissions)` produces a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<JobPermissions>>`, not really sure why.

Comment: if you have navigation properties, there is no need to use `join`

Comment: Apart from anything else: in most cases, these two queries will not return the same results - there is no WHERE call in #1 (emp.Id==empId). Other than that, both queries do exactly the same - apart from some overhead from EF looking for FK's for the navigation property.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Both queries will return the same result. There is no need for a `WHERE` clause because it is implied. `EF` is smart enough to look for the appropriate `Job` and `JobPermissions` because it is noted that they're related to a certain `Employee`.